# ExecJS::RuntimeError in Welcome#index using React.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, coffeescript

I've starting learning the React.js with Rails back-end, and now I'm stuck with a simple task to show the users. The code is the following:

**application.js**:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
//= require_tree .
```

**components.js**:

```
//= require_tree ./components
```

**index.html.erb**:

```
<%= react_component 'Users', { data: @users } %>
```

**assets/javascripts/components/users.js.coffee**:

```
@Users = React.createClass
    getInitialState: ->
        users: @props.data
    getDefaultProps: ->
        users: []
    render: ->
        React.DOM.div null,
            className: 'users'
            for user in @state.users
```

**assets/javascripts/components/user.js.coffee**:

```
@User = React.createClass
    render: ->
        React.DOM.img null, @props.user.avatar
        React.DOM.p null, @props.user.username
```

This code returns me `ExecJS::RuntimeError in Welcome#index`, and the details are:

```
SyntaxError: [stdin]:9:28: unexpected indentation

Extracted source (around line #6):

<head>
    <title>Testingapp</title>
    <!-- the line #6 goes below, stylesheet_link_tag -->
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

I tried to remove

```
//= require tree .
```

from **application.js** and in **components.js** I changed

```
//= require tree ./components
```

line to

```
//= require components
```

and the error then dissapears, but React just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It fails on the `for user in @state.users` line. You can try adding comma  after `className: 'users'`, because React element accepts children as the last argument and that's what you probably was going to do.

You should end up with something like this:

```
render: ->
    React.DOM.div null,
        className: 'users',
        (@User(user: user, key: user.username) for user in users)
```

As a side note, consider turning off server side rendering in react-rails until you have your code working in browser. It'll make debugging much easier.

Comment: thanks! I tried your suggestion, and the error dissapears, but then there's just nothing displayed :(

Comment: Well, you need to start debugging from here. Add some console.log statements all over the place, disable server-side rendering and figure out what's going on. Did you anything to users array? One other thing you can fix right away is `render` function in `@User`: you need to wrap it in a div because otherwise it returns only the latter of two statements,`React.DOM.p`.